# play framework: calling functions in routes file

Tags: scala, playframework, routes

Is it possible to call functions in playframework routes file?.
In the below example if the url path doesn't have instance_id in it, I will have to generate a new one (using `utils.Util.uuid` function) to assign it to the instance_id parameter.

```
POST  /job/instance/start/:jobName/:instanceId   @controllers.JobInstanceController.startInstance(jobName: String, instance_id: String = utils.Util.uuid, label: Option[String])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The router has *one* responsibility: mapping HTTP method and URI patterns to controller methods. If you want to be able to handle two cases (starting a job with an instance id, and one without), you should have two routes: one that handles a job with an existing instance id, and one that expects a job without an instance id (perhaps mapping to an `Option`) in the controller.